# How to output JSON data, from an external API, in jQuery like I see it in the console log, in HTML (formatting JSON in jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Edit: I've had some luck with

```
var items = [];

$.each(response.response.content, function(i, item) { 
  $("#title").append(item.title + " ");

 });
```

I've connected to an external API and can get everything printed out perfectly in my console log, but can only print it out in JSON format on my HTML page. I'm baffled as to why I can't figure out how to get it to print the same way on my page.

```
 <script>
 const settings = {
     "async": true,
     "crossDomain": true,
     "url": "https://learning-objects-v2.p.rapidapi.com/search?keywords=Excel&lang=en&type=video&sort=popularity&model=strict&max=10&page=0",
     "method": "GET",
     "headers": {
         "x-rapidapi-key": "12345678901234567890",
         "x-rapidapi-host": "learning-objects-v2.p.rapidapi.com"
     }
 };

 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

  $('#demo').append(JSON.stringify(response))

 var items = [];

  $.each(response.response.content, function(i, item) { 

 console.log(item);
  });
 });
 </script>
```

And here is some of the JSON

```
 "response":{
 "content":[
 {
 "title":"Normal distribution excel exercise | Probability and Statistics | Khan 
 Academy",
 "url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTGEMoaWDCQ",
 "description":"(Long-26 minutes) Presentation on spreadsheet to show that the normal distribution approximates the binomial distribution for a large number of trials. Watch the next lesson: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/statistics-inferential/normal_distribution/v/ck12-org-normal-distribution-probl...",
 "picture":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yTGEMoaWDCQ/hqdefault.jpg",
 "provider":[
 "YouTube"
 ],
 "bloom":[
 "discover"
 ],
 "type":[
 "Video"
 ],
 "level":-0.5,
  "learningTimeValue":26.07,
 "learningTimeUnit":"min"
```

Here is an example of the console log

```
  {title: "Excel Forecast Function Explained!", url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRrZJpG_S7M", description: "This excel video tutorial provides a basic introdu…ted sales forecast in the future. My Website: ...", picture: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nRrZJpG_S7M/hqdefault.jpg", provider: Array(1), …}
 bloom: ["discover"]
 description: "This excel video tutorial provides a basic introduction into the forecast function which can be used to predict a y value given an x value. It could be used to predict the population at a certain year, the value of a car at a given time, or the estimated sales forecast in the future. My Website: ..."
 learningTimeUnit: "min"
 learningTimeValue: 10.3
 level: -0.5
 picture: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nRrZJpG_S7M/hqdefault.jpg"
 provider: ["YouTube"]
 title: "Excel Forecast Function Explained!"
 type: ["Video"]
 url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRrZJpG_S7M"
```

I know I need to assign 's to it, and put it into a loop, but I'm not sure exactly how, and the books I have open aren't helping much. Thank you kindly!

Comment: What is the expected result? And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: I want to display the results as text with links and images on the page, to format the JSON so it's readable basically, and so far I've tried different Ajax calls and such, a few different solutions through SO, though none have worked, and I'm going through a couple ebooks right now, and different loops, but am getting errors, just the unformatted json, or a blank screen.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68270069/edit) your question and add relevant information as well as your most promising approach there.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `keyname` to access required values i.e : `title,pictures..etc`  .So , inside your each loop get that values and add them inside generated html and finally append this to your *DOM*.
***Demo Code*** :

```js
//just for demo ..suppose response variable have your response :
var response = {
  "response": {
    "content": [{
      "title": "Normal distribution excel exercise | Probability and Statistics | Khan  Academy ",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTGEMoaWDCQ",
      "description": "(Long-26 minutes) Presentation on spreadsheet to show that the normal distribution approximates the binomial distribution for a large number of trials. Watch the next lesson: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/statistics-inferential/normal_distribution/v/ck12-org-normal-distribution-probl...",
      "picture": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yTGEMoaWDCQ/hqdefault.jpg",
      "provider": [
        "YouTube"
      ],
      "bloom": [
        "discover"
      ],
      "type": [
        "Video"
      ],
      "level": -0.5,
      "learningTimeValue": 26.07,
      "learningTimeUnit": "min",
    }, {
      "title": "Normal distribution excel exercise | Probability and Statistics | Khan  Academy2222 ",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTGEMoaWDCQ",
      "description": "(Long-26 minutes) Presentation on spreadsheet to show that the normal distribution approximates the binomial distribution for a large number of trials. Watch the next lesson: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/statistics-inferential/normal_distribution/v/ck12-org-normal-distribution-probl...",
      "picture": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yTGEMoaWDCQ/hqdefault.jpg",
      "provider": [
        "YouTube"
      ],
      "bloom": [
        "discover"
      ],
      "type": [
        "Video"
      ],
      "level": -0.5,
      "learningTimeValue": 26.07,
      "learningTimeUnit": "min",
     
    }]
  }
}
var html = ""
$.each(response.response.content, function(i, item) {
  //just for demo ..
  html += `<div><img src="${item.picture}"/><a href="${item.url}">${item.title}</a></div>`
});
$("#somediv").html(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="somediv"></div>
```